# Nice font from a 1959 French article

Tags: fonts, font-encodings

Here's an excerpt from a 1959 French article I've found:

[image]

(title: "Points rationnels sur certaines courbes et surfaces cubiques", by François Châtelet, from L'Enseignement Mathématique, [here](https://www.e-periodica.ch/digbib/view?lang=en&pid=ens-001%3A1959%3A5%3A%3A307#290))

I'm trying to replicate this on Latex as best as I can.

I know nothing about typography, but it seems to me that the serifs are an important ingredient.

So I've looked for the [serif fonts](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/seriffonts.html) from the Latex Font Catalogue, and the best one (in my opinion) I could find was European Computer Modern:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

[image]

This is also nice, but it doesn't compete with the original. (I can't elaborate why, but I think it's clear)

Does anyone think there is a better alternative? (preferably, a free one)

Thank you!

Comment: What's the title  of the article, and the name of the journal?

Comment: It's a version of Caslon

Comment: @Bernard, I've just included the information in the question.

Comment: You could try https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/ for a font ID.  If the automated system doesn't give a satisfactory result you can submit it to the forum there.

Comment: I think the closest match would be something like Old Standard <https://ctan.org/pkg/oldstandard>.

Answer (score 6):

It's Caslon.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{librecaslon}

\addtolength{\textwidth}{-15pt}
\linespread{1.1}

\begin{document}

\spaceskip=0.4em plus 0.3em minus 0.1em

La recherche des points a coordonnées rationnelles (en abrégé
points rationnels) sur une variété algébrique est un problème
mathématique très ancien; on en trouve des exemples dans les
œuvres de Diophante au {\scriptsize III}\ieme{} siècle de notre ere.
Ce problème a fait l'objet de travaux de mathématiciens les
plus célèbres, tels Fermat, Euler, Lagrange, Gauss, Hilbert,
Poincaré. Pourtant il n'est entièrement résolu que pour des
variétés très particulières~[1].

\end{document}
```

[image]

The LibreCaslon font has a very narrow interword spacing, by default, so I used `\spaceskip` to get a more generous one, like in the picture.

No accompanying math font, I'm afraid. And no small caps either.

Comment: Maybe no small caps, but if you look carefully, the small caps in the original are just a bit taller than the lowercase, and have a bit of letterspacing. It should be possible to fix that.  And, unfortunately, the digit 1 isn't as pretty as the original.

Comment: I don’t think it’s a Caslon. Caslon had a sloping stress on c and e which is not the case in this face.

Comment: The used font is probably near the [Labernia Book](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/tipo-pepel/labernia/book/) font (see for example closely the "t" shape with the magnification glass on the scanned page), but the digits are rather different (see the "4" or the "7" in the next page), and also the italic "v" (see in the ref. 5 of the bibliography in the next page). I don't know if there is a better numeric font (and more : LaTeX friendly). The better to do is probably to ask [the editor](http://www.unige.ch/math/EnsMath/welcome.html) if they know the name of the font used in this issue.